# ExpressionEngine tag for knowing if you're on a entry page or not

Tags: expressionengine

How can you tell inside of a template if the page is being viewed as a single entry page or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the `{total_results}` variable ([link](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/variables.html#var_total_results)) inside of the `{exp:channel:entries}` loop that generates the entries that you are targeting. For instance, if you're displaying entries for a blog, your template code could look something like this:

```
<ul class="entries">    
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}
  {if "{total_results}"=="1"}
    <li class="single-entry">
      {title}
      {content}
    </li>
  {if:else}
    <li class="entry">
      <a href="#">{title}</a>
      <p>{excerpt}</p>
    </li>
  {/if}
  {if no_results}
    <li class="no-entries">No blog entries found.</li>
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are better off checking for the presence of a segment to detect if you are on a single article view. There could be an instance where you only have one channel entry in your index view - eg if you are displaying news per month and its only 1st of the month.

By checking if segment_2 = url_title you'll also be able to keep pagination working correctly as /channel/p1 will work.

```
{if segment_2=="{url_title}"}  
    // show description
{if:else}
    // show summary
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the insight from [onlinepluz](http://www.onlinepluz.com), consider it like

```js
{if segment_2=="{url_title}"}  
        // show description
    {if:else}
        // show summary
    {/if}
```